# Authorize.NET Customer Payment Profiles

Tags: authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

I am planning to introduce a feature into our application, so that the member can choose existing customer profiles that are created by his card previously created.

Following are the question:

1. How to validate that the customer profile is still valid and its card is not expired?
2. Is it a good approach to allow members to choose existing profiles?
3. If we do not allow to choose, then using the same card with a different invoice #, allows us to create ARB, but it also creates a new customer profile. That way, there can be thousands of profiles in few years. How Authorize.NET handle such data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to validate that the customer profile is still valid and its card is not expired?

You will need to keep track of this on your end if your goal is to be proactive about managing this. There currently is no API call that will tell you if a card is expired or expiring soon.

> Does it a good approach to allow members to choose existing profiles?

Sure. This is a handy feature and letting your users choose what payment method they want to use is never a bad idea.

> If we do not allow to choose, then using the same card with a different invoice #, allows us to create ARB, but it also creates a new customer profile. That way, there can be thousands of profiles in few years. How Authorize.NET handle such data?

They can easily handle large amounts of profiles. All you need to do is make sure your system can, too.